# MediaSource API Demo Not Working(Chrome)

Tags: javascript, html, api, video, streaming

I am newbie as far as HTML5 is concerned. I was going through **MediaSource API** documentation given on [this link](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/11/Stream-video-using-the-MediaSource-API)

I visited the demo link given on [this link](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/media-source.html)

But it did not work(under chrome) . When i checked through developer tools i am getting following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: MediaSource is not defined
```

In documentation it was mentioned that :

```
Support: Currently, the MediaSource API is only available in Chrome Dev Channel 17+ with the --enable-media-source flag set or enabled via about:flags.
```

I have already enabled media-source flag and my chrome version is **21.0.1180.79 m**

How to make this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The demo is working with neither stable channel nor dev channel, but with latest canary (m23) build. The documentation you were referring is outdated. You can find the latest version of spec draft [here](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html).

Also, check [this](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119309) Chrome issue. I am not sure about one thing mentioned there. It is said that the demo is updated to work with v0.5 API. But the demo code matches more with the example given at latest spec compared to that at v0.5. May be they are just two different ways of achieving the same thing.

Comment: I've update the demo to work with the v0.5 spec. That's current Chrome 23 (Canary)

Comment: Thanks @ebidel. I was able to run the same kind of demo with ISO BMFF as well.  When can I see the demo on mobile Chrome? :)

Answer (score 2):

The state of this experimental API has been in flux over the last few versions of Chrome.

- Chrome 17-20 have the v0.3 API which is what the article's code snippet shows.
- Chrome 21 & 22 have the v0.5 API which is what was originally proposed to the W3C.
- Chrome 23 has the new [object-oriented API](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/html-media/raw-file/tip/media-source/media-source.html) that is currently being standardized. The demo was updated to this version of the API.

If you want to convert the v0.3 example to the v0.5 API that your version of Chrome 21 supports, just follow [these instructions](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=119309#c13).

If you don't mind running a Canary build or can wait until Chrome 23 comes to the dev channel, then you should definitely use the object oriented API. It is more powerful than the older versions and it actually reflects what is being standardized.